# [Noun 1]は[Noun 2]が[Adjective] or [Noun 1]の[Noun 2]は[Adjective]

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-は, particle-の, particle-が

Consider the phrase: *The Winters of Quebec are cold.*

I understand that the correct form is

```
ケベックは冬が寒いです。
```

Since a possessive form is involved here (the Winters **of** Quebec), why is

```
ケベックの冬は寒いです。
```

not correct?

Comment: `why is ケベックの冬は寒いです。not correct?` -- I think it's correct... It sounds perfectly natural to me... (Did anyone tell you it's not correct?)

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are fine. They only have slightly different meaning, and you would use one or the other depending on context, for example:

Ex.1: "Where do you live?" "I live in Quebec" "Winters are cold in Quebec, aren't they?"

(ケベックは冬が寒いですね - "As for Quebec, winters are cold" - The topic is Quebec, something that have came up in the conversation, and the speaker elaborates on that topic suggesting that it has cold winters)

Ex.2: "It's winter now in Quebec" "Winters are cold in Quebec, aren't they?"

(ケベックの冬は寒いですね - "As for Winters of Quebec, they're cold" - The topic is "winters of Quebec", which have just came up in the conversation, and the speaker elaborates on that topic suggesting they're cold)